# Как вывести в терминал значения до обновления, после обновления и вставленные значения?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Подскажите пожалуйста как при выполнении кода ниже можно добавить вывод значений которые были обновлены, значения до обновления и вставленные значения?
К примеру хочется видеть в выводе следующую информацию:

```
f"""[%(asctime)s] В таблице {Table} для {primary_key} было обновлено значение {column_name}: {old_value} -> {new_value}"""
```

Где Table - это `Table.__table_name__` таблицы, primary_key - это первичные ключи для которых обновлено значение(`Table.__table__.primary_key`), column_name - название столбца где было обновление, old_value | new_value - старое | новое значение соответственно

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as pg_insert    

def upsert_table(
        self,
        tname: Base,
        df: DataFrame
    ) -> None:

        with self.Session as session:
            stmt = pg_insert(tname).values(df)
            stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
                constraint=tname.__table__.primary_key,
                set_=stmt.excluded
            )

            session.execute(stmt)
            session.commit()
```

Я пытался использовать декоратор listens_for для этого, но у меня так и не получилось вывести в обработчик событий информацию об обновленных значениях

Comment: Создайте таблицу в которой будете регистрировать изменения значений. Создайте триггер (триггеры) которые будут регистрировать изменения значений, ну и так далее (но думаю это уже не SqlAlchemy, это прямо вот уже программирование базы данных)

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо за ответ. Такие таблицы и триггеры у меня есть для определенных таблиц для отслеживания истории изменений, но хотелось бы записывать данные об обновлении в лог файл

Comment: Ну и кто Вам мешает их оттуда достать и вывести в лог?

Comment: @Namerek Мне не хочется для каждой таблицы создавать таблицу изменений, это в целом не сложно, но значительно увеличивает нагрузку на поддержку

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не знаю как из SqlAlchemy вызвать returning, а так-то прям вот оно

Comment: @Namerek, а не могли бы Вы привести пример как это сделать в PostgreSql, я разберусь как returning вызывать

Comment: `insert into users (id, name) values (1, 'Vasya') returning id, name` и забираете из курсора которым это запускали данные